# Python pyodbc connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server Express using pyodbc, however I get an error.

This is the code I wrote:

```
import pyodbc
cnx = pyodbc.connect("DSN=mydsn;UID=user;PWD=mypassword;port=1433")
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM T_tableA;")
for row in cursor:
    print row.name
```

After ran the program, the result returned.

> #python odbctest.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "odbctest.py", line 7, in 
> print row.name
> AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'name'

Using isql on terminal, successfully connected to SQL Server.

Can anyone help me with this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the table structure, I think there is no name column

Comment: Hi Mohammad! exactly what's you pointed out. my table does not have "name"column. now I can get record. Thanks a lot!